# Post request works as node script, but not on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, react-native, post

I have this post request to JIRA to create an issue:

```
require('isomorphic-fetch');
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var summ = "Review Test Ticket";
var issue = {
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "ABC"
       },
       "summary": summ,
       "description": "This is a test JIRA issue creation",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Story"
       },
       "assignee": {
           "name": "myname"
       },
       "customfield_10902": [{ "value": "Red Team" }],
       "customfield_10008": 1
   }
};

var missue = JSON.stringify(issue)
fetch("https://my_jira_host/jira/rest/api/2/issue/", {
    body: missue,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic my_auth_token",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    method: "POST"
})
.then(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

If the above code is in a file called "my_file.js" if I run `node my_file.js` the ticket is successfully created.
However, if I move that code inside a function that runs on button click in my react app, and then run the app (on localhost or a server) then it fails. I get a 403. The alert displayed from my catch is: `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

I have tried absolutely everything. Have no idea where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: A 403 would indicate you are Forbidden. Is it possible the auth token is being passed incorrectly when running from your react app? If you're sure the auth token is present and correct, and since it seems to be working when running from console, it might be a CORS issue with the JIRA server (although that usually does not return a 403)

Comment: The code is exactly the same, copy-pasted over. So I know for sure that the auth token is identical.

Comment: Is the react app you're running this code from https also? Since it works in the console and not the browser, it sounds like a browser security issue. Again, maybe CORS, calling out to HTTPS from an HTTP site, or some other browser limitation. Have you tried running it in JSFiddle to rule out any network issues?

Comment: It doesn't work in the browser when you run the same code but it does work in node.js?The  "Content-Type": "application/json" alone will make this a CORS request and if you use chrome on localhost with self signed certificate this won't work at all. You should be able to see all of this in chrome developers console. The latter you can mitigate for a test with chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost.

Comment: Turns out this is likely an OAuth error. When running from a script, Jira is ok with basic authentication, but when coming from a server, I think it requires OAuth authentication. I will touch back and confirm when I've successfully implemented OAuth (if it works)